# How can I swipe to a specific value in espresso automation?

Tags: android, automation, android-espresso

I wanted to select a specific value in a date picker on the android app.

In the below screen, I have performed the `swipeDown()` action but it is swiping to any value.
Here as part of automation, I want to swipe to a specific value.

Screen on the app
[image: Screen on the app]